# CarrierWave extension_white_list doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to use CarrierWave's `extension_white_list` method:

```
def extension_white_list
  [/jpe?g/, 'gif', 'png']
end
```

Now whenever I upload anything (even jpegs and pngs), I get a `CarrierWave::IntegrityError`

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is completely related to your problem but I just lost a couple hours until I discovered they changed from `extension_white_list` to `extension_whitelist` which breaks everyones code! https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594901/135767

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem was I was uploading to S3 and it couldn't grab the extension for some reason.

Comment: How did you fix this?  I'm having the same issue for EPS files.  Even after I commented out the whitelist method it won't upload an EPS file.  EDIT: And PDFs

Comment: This is not an answer. What is the actual solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with ['jpeg', 'jgp', 'png', 'gif'] ?

It seems the regex is messing up the call because it is supposed to be an array of "words" (see [Rails - Using %W](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455429/rails-using-w)) that extension_white_list contains.

Comment: Yeah. This example is taken right from their documentation: http://rdoc.info:8080/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/master/CarrierWave/Uploader/ExtensionWhitelist

Comment: Is server you're uploading the file to changing the extension? 

Is the file fully uploaded before this is checked?

Throwing out anything I can think of :) I would have posted my 'answer' as a comment but I'm not allowed to comment on things that aren't my own.