# carrierwave extension_white_list not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, carrierwave

here is a similar case but no solution [CarrierWave extension_white_list doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348510/carrierwave-extension-white-list-doesnt-seem-to-work)
Carrierwave provides a function `extension_white_list` which is supposed to prevent a user from uploading an invalid file. I have uncommented this function but how do I handle this case? I want to catch this error and inform the user that he should change the file.

this wiki entry seems relevant but I'm not sure how to proceed https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-uploads-with-Active-Record

Answer (score 12):

According to this issue https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1896

The solution is this and it worked for me;

change:

```
def extension_white_list
end
```

to:

```
def extension_whitelist
end
```

so they have removed the underscore from whitelist word.

Comment: I can't believe they did that without creating an alias. That is a security breach for almost like every rails app. 
Thanks for this info @"Shuaib Zahda"
 , very useful!!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your model, `validates_integrity_of :avatar` will cause whitelist violations to act much like `validates_presence_of :another_field` would with a blank field when saving, i.e. `save` will return false, after which `valid?` will be false and there will be a pertinent error message available in `user.errors[:avatar]`.